# SQL Server : why convert to date use index and convert to nvarchar not?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have the following 2 queries with function on the index, one do index seek and one index scan:

This uses the index:

```
select num_of_row 
from test0
where convert(date, index_date) = '2017-06-13'
```

This does not use the index:

```
select num_of_row 
from test0
where convert(nvarchar, index_date, 103) = '2017-06-13'
```

Why is the index used when I convert to `date`, but not when I convert to `nvarchar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you can't use any functions for a field if you want it to be SARGable (=to use index), but datetime -> date is one of the exceptions, most likely because the order can be guaranteed to be the same (in dates and datetimes), but not in datetimes and (n)varchars.